# Issue with for loop printing out entire array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am practicing with arrays and loops and am running into an issue with this piece of code. When printing out, it doesn't print out all of the names. It only prints:

`I know someone called Athena`

```js
    var names = ["Paul", "Becky", "Aubrie", "Zeus", "Athena"];
    var x = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += x) {
        console.log("I know someone called " + names[i]);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Worksforme, printing all five names

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Sometimes, depending on your browser (Firefox?), `console.log` statements in close succession will collapse into each other. Is there a red '5' over on the right indicating the console has printed 5 times?

Comment: I get this error in the learning software I am using....`TypeError: console.log is not a function`

Comment: What browser are you on

Comment: Are you using a really old version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: I am doing it in a online learning course.

Comment: @Becky you haven't answered the question about the browser.

Comment: Yes, but what browser are you using to access the course?

Comment: If you are indeed using Chrome then it seems that perhaps the page you are on has hijacked the console object. Otherwise I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure, it is a popular code learning program. I am not sure why it is saying that console.log is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit weird way of looping, but you're practicing, so fine. However, your code works properly. Here is a demo:

```js
var names = ["Paul", "Becky", "Aubrie", "Zeus", "Athena"];
var x = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += x) {
    document.write("<br/>I know someone called " + names[i]);
}
```

Comment: It is making me use console.log, it is a way of checking to see if the problem is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. What is making you use `console.log`? You mean your instructor? `console.log` should work too, but perhaps you have an issue with your code learning program. We don't know about it so we cannot help you, but your code is fine.

Comment: I'm using codeacademy to do this and is requires I write `console.log`... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nevermind, the site must have crashed and not re-loaded my answer. It worked. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Yeah, I've just checked it on codeacademy and it worked with `console.log` too. :-).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var names = ["Paul", "Becky", "Aubrie", "Zeus", "Athena"];

for (var i = 0; names.length > i; i++) {
    console.log("I know someone called " + names[i]);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcwpo2kh/)

Answer (score 0):

more compact

```js
var names = ["Paul", "Becky", "Aubrie", "Zeus", "Athena"];
    for (var i in names) {
        document.write("I know someone called " + names[i] + "<br>");
    }
```